# Traits with GAT as a method generic argument: "borrowed value does not live long enough"

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to write a function that takes a generic argument over a trait with a [GAT](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/10/28/gats-stabilization.html).

Here is my code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=61296550664cb8b7cd9c225b02cafaff)):

```rust
struct Owned;

struct Ref<'a> {
    owned: &'a Owned,
}

trait Abstract {
    type Input<'a>;
    fn method(&self, _input: &Self::Input<'_>);
}

struct Concrete;

impl Abstract for Concrete {
    type Input<'a> = Ref<'a>;
    fn method(&self, _input: &Self::Input<'_>) {}
}

fn act<'a, A>(abs: A) where A: Abstract<Input<'a> = Ref<'a>> {
    let owned = Owned {};
    let obj_ref = Ref { owned: &owned } ;
    abs.method(&obj_ref);
}

// This works, but I'd prefer building the owned value inside the function.
// fn act2<'a, A>(abs: A, owned: &'a Owned) where A: Abstract<Input<'a> = Ref<'a>> {
//     let obj_ref = Ref { owned } ;
//     abs.method(&obj_ref);
// }
```

I'm trying to get the method `act` to work. The error I'm getting:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0597]: `owned` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:21:32
   |
19 | fn act<'a, A>(abs: A) where A: Abstract<Input<'a> = Ref<'a>> {
   |        -- lifetime `'a` defined here
20 |     let owned = Owned {};
21 |     let obj_ref = Ref { owned: &owned } ;
   |                                ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
22 |     abs.method(&obj_ref);
   |     -------------------- argument requires that `owned` is borrowed for `'a`
23 | }
   | - `owned` dropped here while still borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

I understand the problem and why it doesn't work, but I'm unsure how to fix it. I found a workaround with the method `act2`, which is a reasonable solution, but that forces me to create the `Owned` object outside of the method, which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to have a reference to a thing that's owned by the current function `owned` in `act` live as long as the caller wants it to `'a` because it gets dropped at the end of the function `}` in line 23. In the end the `Owned` struct has to be stored somewhere.

But if `Owned` is a literal you can exploit static promotion like this:

```rust
fn act<'a, A>(abs: A) where A: Abstract<Input<'a> = Ref<'a>> {
    let obj_ref = Ref { owned: &Owned } ;
    abs.method(&obj_ref);
}
```

You can also not let the caller of `act` determine the lifetime by using [HRTBs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) instead of a generic lifetime:

```rust
fn act<A>(abs: A) where for<'a> A: Abstract<Input<'a> = Ref<'a>> {
    let owned = Owned;
    let obj_ref = Ref { owned: &owned } ;
    abs.method(&obj_ref);
}
```

Comment: Generics on the method didn't work either. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c545ae61ac07702667c053e001e44f38)

Comment: I can't build Owned as a literal in my case.

Comment: Then you can't let the caller of `act` determine the lifetime `'a`, see my last edit.

Comment: Fantastic! TIL about HRTBs. This is exactly what I was looking for!